# 403 - Forbidden and Server trusts so many certificate authorities that the list has grown too long

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, wcf-security

We have a web application under default website using client certificate authentication to authenticate its client. It is failing in handshaking with client certificate for authentication and errored out with either timeout or 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied error.
We found below error on system event logs,

> When asking for client authentication, this server sends a list of
>   trusted certificate authorities to the client. The client uses this
>   list to choose a client certificate that is trusted by the server.
>   Currently, this server trusts so many certificate authorities that the
>   list has grown too long. This list has thus been truncated. The
>   administrator of this machine should review the certificate
>   authorities trusted for client authentication and remove those that do
>   not really need to be trusted.

IIS configuration looks much similar to what we have done for this web application on other environments, we verified couple of other checks required for this application
In certificate Store: We verified all server certificate and client cert with its authority hierarchy are available.
Application Authentication: Anonymous
Application SSL Setting: Require SSL/ Accept
ApplicationHost.config: enabled OnetoOneMapping under iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication also added base64 certificate mapped with service accounts

I am not sure this authentication issue has to do anything with above error message in event log.

Comment: Did you check Windows Certificate store -> LocalMachine -> Trusted Root Certificate Authorities as well as Intermediate Certificate Authorities list? Do they contain too many CAs?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is probably too late to help the OP, but for anyone else with this event log message, there is a well-structured post on this issue at https://www.codit.eu/blog/2013/04/03/troubleshooting-ssl-client-certificate-issue-on-iis/, which suggests:

> There are two solutions to solve this issue:
>
> The first solution is to clean up the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store (Local Machine) and remove all unnecessary certificates. Be aware that you don’t remove certificates that are required by Windows.
>
> A second solution is to configure Schannel to no longer send the list of trusted root certification authorities during the TLS/SSL handshake process.  This can be done by adding this registry entry on the web server
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
>
> Value name: SendTrustedIssuerList 
>   Value type: REG_DWORD 
>   Value data: 0 (False)